# Display an element in the middle of its parent vertically

Tags: html, css, label, dropdown

This is how the selector looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the text appears near the bottom of the selector, I want it to be situated in the middle vertically, horizontally it is fine like that, near the left side.

The selector element:

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root searchPlatform"></div>
```

has:

```
border: 0;
margin: 0;
display: inline-flex;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
min-width: 0;
flex-direction: column;
vertical-align: top;
```

and the text "Platform" is a label: `<label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-outlined">`

I've tried to add     `vertical-align: middle;` in its style but doesn't change its position.

How can it be positioned in the middle vertically?

Comment: For flexbox the attributes are `align-item` and `justify-content`. You can find more explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Apprendre/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`justify-content` is one possible way to go:

```css
.searchPlatform {
 /* for demo purposes*/ 
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: top;
  
  /* "new" code */
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="MuiFormControl-root searchPlatform"><label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-outlined">Platform</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : You should use display as flex as display as well as justify-content and align-items properties to center will align the contents in the center (in both axis).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .center {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 200px;
        border: 3px solid green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <button>this is a button</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.center {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 200px;
        border: 3px solid green;
      }
```

```html
<div class="center">
      <button>this is a button</button>
    </div>
```